# How to import table structure only from csv file into Access

Tags: csv, ms-access, vba

I would like to import a CSV file into Access as a table, but table structure only.

`TransferText` does not have the choice `StructureOnly` as `TransferDatabase` does. How can I code in VB to import table structure only from a csv file.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a 0-row import from the CSV file using a query:

```
SELECT *
INTO StructureOnlyTable
FROM [Text;FMT=CSVDelimited;HDR=Yes;DATABASE=C:\Path\To].[MyFile#csv]
WHERE 1=0
```

Note that this does use a different process than TransferText, and does require you to specify your import parameters in a very different way. See more about how to configure your import [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/initializing-the-text-data-source-driver)

Answer (score 0):

Import the table using the `TransferText` method and then simply clear the table using something like:

```vb
DoCmd.RunSQL "delete from YourTable"
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice but this is exactly what I try to aviod. Importing a huge csv file can take significant amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

Import the table as a linked file, then copy and paste the table as structure only.